# How do I get excel to search and change cell information in specific column?

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I need to change all numbers from a specific column to text and the macros I'm using at the moment, changes all numbers in the whole database to letters, instead of just the specified column H. 
Here's the Macros I'm currently using. what should I add to the beginning of it to specify to search only in Column H? I'd like to keep the majority of my macro if possible.
Thank you!

```
    Sub EOD_Process_Part_2()
[![From and To][1]][1]    '----Changes all Numbers to initials----

Columns("H3:H").Select
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
    Selection.Replace what:="1", Replacement:="AM", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace what:="2", Replacement:="B", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace what:="3", Replacement:="BM", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace what:="4", Replacement:="BS", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

'--------------- adds missing and no initials-------------

    Columns("H:H").Select
    Range("H2").Activate
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Replace what:="", Replacement:="MISSING", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=True
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Replace what:="-", Replacement:="?", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=True
    Range("H2").Select

Selection.AutoFilter
Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 11.29
Range("L7").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the range to replace without selecting it :

```
Dim columnH As Range  ' to specify that the variable columnH is of type Range
Set columnH = ActiveCell.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns("H")
Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear

columnH.Replace "1", "AM", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
columnH.Replace "2", "B"
columnH.Replace "3", "BM"
columnH.Replace "4", "BS"

Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow 
columnH.Replace "" , "MISSING", ReplaceFormat:=True

Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior.Color =  XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue
columnH.Replace "-", "?"
```

Another way can be to check the cells one by one

```
Dim cell As Range, columnH As Range
Set columnH = ActiveCell.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns("H")

For Each cell in columnH.Cells
    Select CStr(cell.Value)
        Case "1" : cell.Value = "AM"
        Case "2" : cell.Value = "B"
        Case "3" : cell.Value = "BM"
        Case "4" : cell.Value = "BS"

        Case ""  : cell.Value = "MISSING"
                   cell.Interior.Color = rgbYellow

        Case "-" : cell.Value = "?"
                   cell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
                   cell.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did what it was supposed to, but the colours I assigned to the Missing and ? cells didn't show up. how do I add that in?

Comment: An error pops up when I tried to assign colour to Replace "-", "?" This is the code I used, and excel says that .Replace is an unqualified reference. Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightBlue
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Replace "-", "?", ReplaceFormat:=True

Comment: I removed and changed some of the code to make it a bit easier

Comment: Hey! It's ok, I figured it out, thanks. I put the update of what I have below in the answers part for other people's reference, as that's the only place that has space. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your range better.  Avoid `Select` and `Activate` as much as possible.  Don't search over 1 million rows if you don't have to.  Determine the last row needed from the column and limit the number of rows to search.

For example:

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(Xlup).Row

Set SRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(3,8),ws1.Cells(LastRow, 8))

With SRng
'Add in all your search and format stuff
End With
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The column itself can run as long as 40 rows or so. It changes every time and can be unpredictable, I need for this macro to work with any sheet in the workbook, so I do I just do this? Set ws1 = ActiveSheet?

Comment: That is why the LastRow is used.  It will change with the amount of data, known as dynamic.  I don't know what you put in between the `With` and `End With`, but this will limit your range to the number of rows in Column H between 3 and the LastRow.  You might have something else going on or did not properly insert the search information.  You don't even need all the extra commands for the replace...

Comment: @DarrellHarrieThis is what I got now, and it seems to be working ok. But it's still not covering the right range. I just basically pasted what you saw above in between where you said to put it. Sub EOD_Process_Part_2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 200).End(xlUp).Row

Set SRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(3, 8), ws1.Cells(LastRow, 200))
'----Changes all Numbers to initials----
    Range("H3:H168").Activate `<---- how do I change the H168 to include all active rows? Because that number of rows will always change
    Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear

Comment: I also took out the Select and Active part of the code.

Comment: You put row 200 in the range definition and the LastRow column.  If you only want Column H, it is column 8.  You do not need to `Activate` the range.  The last row formula determines how many rows exist in the column.

Comment: The macro works now! I figured out what I did wrong. I didn't highlight the column before I executed the Macro. I was wondering, is there a way to select all active rows in Column H  automatically?

Comment: That is what the LastRow line was meant to do.  Rows.Count goes to the last row in the sheet, then End(xlup) is the same as hitting the End key and the up arrow to get to the next non-empty row.  You don't need to select or highlight for the code to work.

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work. It searched the whole document when I processed the macro without any adjusting. So I decided to run this part of the Macro by itself:
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

LastRow = ws1.Cells(Row.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

Set SRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(3, 8), ws1.Cells(LastRow, 8))
End Sub
to see if it'll select column H, it came back with "LastRow = ws1.Cells(Row.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row" as an error. Did I do somethin wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is my end result from what user Slai the Macros master created above. 
Thanks Slai!

```
Sub EOD_Process_Part_2()

'-------Changes assigned numbers to right initials-------

     Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
With ActiveCell.Worksheet.UsedRange.Range("H:H")
    .Replace "1", "AM", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    .Replace "2", "B"
    .Replace "3", "BM"
    .Replace "4", "BS"

'-------Changes Blanks to MISSING with yellow background-------

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Replace "", "MISSING", ReplaceFormat:=True

'-------Changes NO INITIAL to NO INITIAL with green background-------

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Replace "NO INITIAL", "NO INITIAL", ReplaceFormat:=True

'-------Changes - to ? with light blue background-------

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 14260581
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .Replace "-", "?", ReplaceFormat:=True

'-------Centers Column H and adjusts the column's width-------

    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 11.29
    Range("L7").Select
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for your help!